# Структура таблиц mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, foreign-key

Прошу совета по структуре таблиц.

Допустим, есть таблица **countries** (Страны. Напр. Россия):

```
country_id (PK)
country_name
```

Далее таблица **districts** (Округа. Напр.: Центральный федеральный округ):

```
district_id (PK)
district_name

country_id (FK countries(country_id))
```

Так же есть таблица **subjects** (Субъекты. Напр.: Московская область):

```
subject_id (PK)
subject_name

district_id (FK districts(district_id))
country_id (FK countries(country_id))
```

И еще таблица **cities** (Города):

```
city_id (PK)
city_name

subject_id (FK subjects(subject_id ))
district_id (FK countries(district_id))
country_id (FK countries(country_id))
```

Вопрос:

Правильно ли организована структура?

Либо нужно удалить дополнительные внешние ключи из нижних таблиц и делать выборку по иерархии? Если да - то почему?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: *Правильно ли организована структура?* Нет. Она допускает противоречивые данные. Например, subject 1 может одновременно ссылаться на country 1 и на district 1, который ссылается на country 2.

Comment: Согласен с @Akina, оформите как ответ?

Comment: Удалить то ключи и делать выборку по иерархии то можно и даже нужно. Но для начала надо бы описать более точно задачу. Например, что делать если в какой либо стране нет понятия субъектов ? Или в каких то странах может быть более 2х уровней иерархии территориального деления ...

Comment: Вот, францию например посмотрите http://www.lovefrance.ru/adm_division.htm  вопрос в том, а требуется ли для вашей задачи точное административное деление "как в жизни", что от этого зависит. потому что если требуется, то единственным выходом была бы иерархическая таблица. Правда для работы с такой таблицей надо выбрать любую СУБД, кроме mysql, потому что несчастливой случайности конкретно в mysql работать с такими таблицами еще тот геморрой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привязки лишние. Возможны противоречивые данные. Например город может находится в одной стране, а регион в другой. Не храните в таблице города страны (например), получайте к ним доступ по иерархии.

UPD:либо можно привязываться непосредственно к "родителю"

```
country_id (PK)
country_name
```

---

```
district_id (PK)
district_name

country_id (FK countries(country_id))
```

---

```
subject_id (PK)
subject_name

district_id (FK districts(district_id))
country_id (FK districts(country_id))
```

Comment: А вот это `FK districts(country_id)` невозможно. Внешний ключ должен ссылаться на уникальное поле, лучше на первичный ключ

Comment: @Mike тогда просто убрать fk

Comment: но тогда получаем то же что было к вопросе ТС. можем установить страну не соответствующую округу

Comment: @Mike тогда остается лишь вариант с иерархией. В любом случаи можно напихать внешних проверок, и этим самым гарантировать верную структуру. Создать триггеры,например.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии!